# Should I integrate my business website into my Wordpress website?

Tags: wordpress, user-interface

We're currently in the process of enhancing our business website to include a blogging section, and we're considering using WordPress for its blogging capabilities. Our team frequently posts blogs, and WordPress would allow non-programmer members to contribute content freely while taking advantage of its SEO optimization features. So, we are thinking on migrating our main website to Wordpress.

The problem is the limitations in customizing the UI to align with our desired website design.

One solution we're considering is to maintain our main business website separate from WordPress and include a link on the business website's blog page to redirect visitors to the WordPress blog. This approach would allow us to keep the existing website design intact while utilizing WordPress for our blogging needs. Are there alternative solutions we should consider in integrating WordPress with our business website? Thank you